# Problem using "InputStream" in HTTP GET Method - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new in Android programming and want to read a URL with GET method.
I tried these codes:

```
fun readURL(urlString: String): String {
    var response = ""
    val url = URL(urlString)
    val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    connection.requestMethod = "GET"
    val inputStream = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(connection.inputStream)) // Here crash
    var inputLine: String?
    while (inputStream.readLine().also { inputLine = it } != null) {
        response += inputLine
    }
    inputStream.close()
    connection.disconnect()
    return response
}
```

and

```
    val oracle = URL("http://www.oracle.com/")
    val yc: URLConnection = oracle.openConnection()
    val `in` = BufferedReader(
        InputStreamReader(
            yc.getInputStream() // Here crash
        )
    )
    var inputLine: String?
    while (`in`.readLine().also { inputLine = it } != null) println(inputLine)
    `in`.close()
    return "ss"
```

In both Code I get crash in the lines commented with "// Here crash" and exits the program.

I also tried this code:

```
fun get(url: String): InputStream? {
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build()
    val response = client.newCall(request).execute() // hier crash
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        return response.body?.byteStream()
    }
    return null
}
```

and again get crash in showed line.
I checked the internet connection with a piece of code and it returns true... I also have added these permissions in Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0")
```

in gradle. But still I can't connect to a URL.
[Here](https://ln5.sync.com/dl/23a8796e0/d7yy82dm-7qqidsq4-cwrnn49d-9uhuzrpu) I added a link for viewing the `logcat` file for 3 above code respectively.

Thanks for any help

Comment: For http on Android 11 devices you have to do something extra. Please post the relevant logcat lines.

Comment: please post the logs as seen in `Logcat`. I suspect you are making a network request on the main thread